# Custom Button created in IB does not allow access to custom methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an iOS app with multiple ViewControllers.  Each view has numerous IB generated UIButtons, each set to custom.  I need to change the color of the background in normal and highlighted states.  Further, I need to vary the colors to an RGB value based on user interaction.  Thus, I can't use image files.

I found an example of a custom class derived from UIButton that implements the color change and click methods to change the colors as I desired.  I created a test button and changed its IB custom class to my new class.

I have an outlet property for my IB created button.

The problem I am having is in the viewcontroller.m file when I attempt to access the custom method in my class, xcode can't see the methods.

Comment: Is your IBoutlet set to this custum class instead of UIButton? Are those methods public in the custom class (are they in the .h)?

Comment: Mention some coding where are you facing problem - Your problem is not clear

Comment: Thank you ALL.  Edwin, you hit it on the head.  I had not changed the type of my IBAction to my custom button class.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `IBAction` as a return type for that method
- Declare that particular method in `.h` file

Comment: Tried that with no success.  I had to cast my viewcontroller button with the custom class to get it to see the method.